___isPlatformVersionAtLeast error while building for MacOSx versions
I am developing an AI chat desktop application targeting Apple M chips. The app utilizes embedding models and reranker models, for which I chose Rust-Bert due to its capability to handle such models efficiently. Rust-Bert relies on tch, the Rust bindings for LibTorch.
To enhance the user experience, I want to bundle the LibTorch library, specifically for the MPS (Metal Performance Shaders) backend, with the application. This would prevent users from needing to install LibTorch separately, making the app more user-friendly.
However, I am having trouble locating precompiled binaries of LibTorch for the MPS backend that can be bundled directly into the application via the cargo build.rs file. I need help finding the appropriate binaries or an alternative solution to bundle the library with the app during the build process.
This is the build.rs file
use std::env;
use dirs::home_dir;

fn main() {
    // Set the minimum macOS version to 11.0 (required for `___isPlatformVersionAtLeast`)
    // Link necessary macOS system frameworks
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-framework");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=CoreML");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-framework");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=Foundation");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-framework");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=CoreFoundation");

    // Optionally, specify any other necessary paths for your libraries (for example, LibTorch)
    if let Some(home_dir) = dirs::home_dir() {
        let libtorch_path = home_dir.join(".pyano").join("binaries");
        let libtorch_path_str = libtorch_path.to_str().expect("Invalid libtorch path");

        // Tell cargo to pass the library search path
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", libtorch_path_str);
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-Wl,-rpath,{}", libtorch_path_str);

        // Link your LibTorch libraries here if necessary
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=torch_cpu");
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=torch");
        println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=c10");
    }
}


When I am building this for arm architecture
cargo build --target aarch64-apple-darwin

and my .cargo/config.toml
[target.aarch64-apple-darwin]
linker = "clang"
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-mmacosx-version-min=11.0"]

I am getting this error while building the project on my Apple M1 chip machine.
= note: ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++', '-lc10', '-liconv', '-ltorch', '-ltorch_cpu'
          Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
            "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
                -[CoreMLExecution predict:outputs:getOutputTensorDataFn:] in libort_sys-1d12fa9f293e09c5.rlib[55](model.mm.o)
          ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
          clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


No matter what I am doing (Also tried after deleting the whole build.rs file) I am getting this error.
I have updated my Xcode to version 15 also.

Adding:
println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=Metal");    // Link Metal for MPS
println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=Accelerate");  // Link Accelerate for hardware acceleration

Precompiled LibTorch binaries for the MPS backend are not officially available for non-intel chip, so you may need to build LibTorch from source with MPS support.
You can see discussion here if you want to take different approach then what I offer.
Do:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
cd pytorch

Install the dependencies for macOS as described in the PyTorch from source documentation.
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0 python3 setup.py develop

Modify build.rs
if let Some(home_dir) = dirs::home_dir() {
    let libtorch_path = home_dir.join(".pyano").join("binaries"); // Change to the right path
    let libtorch_path_str = libtorch_path.to_str().expect("Invalid libtorch path");

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search={}", libtorch_path_str); 
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=-Wl,-rpath,{}", libtorch_path_str);

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=torch_cpu");  // Link built libraries
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=torch");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=c10");
}

